# Laptop shuts down randomly

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, shutdown

**Model: HP Pavillion 15-e010au**

I had a water damage accident about a year ago. Milk spill. Since then i have left the laptop in the closet for a year.

Now when i turn on the laptop:
Battery power: Immediately shuts down with power light turned on, wifi light turned on and fan running at full speed.

Plugged in: Power on and runs normally but randomly shuts down with power light turned on, wifi light turned on and fan running at full speed.

I have tried removing the battery and reinserting it. Is this damage to the battery or the power cord or neither.

Thanks

Comment: For a year? Why? Does event viewer show anything? What if you remove battery but still plug it in and turn on (so turned on with no battery)

Comment: When you say "shuts down", exactly what happens, because it doesn't sound shut down to me.

Comment: The screens go black and the light indicators on the side with the power icon and storage icon turns off

Comment: The laptop didnt turn on so i just kinda forgot about it. I tried to turn it on today and this happens. The computer turns on normally without the battery but plugged in

Comment: Well, it seems you've answered your question. The battery seems fried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lap top battery has drained because it was not charged.

The *water damage*, which was milk, could have damaged your motherboard, if it was not properly cleaned.

This is an article about spills:
http://www.geeksquad.com/intelligence/blog/laptops-and-liquids-a-cautionary-tale/

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by the laptop baterry was drain because it was not charged?

Comment: @pixel Some batteries can be damaged if they are not charged and remain fully discharged (without power) for a long period of time.

Comment: @aea2002 Welcome to SU, IMO i think you are incorrect(in this scenario), because if you read the OP carefully there is an "accident with milk" that means a 90% of chances to have elecrical damage,

Comment: What are possible fixes for this problem. Would a replacement battery be sufficient?

Comment: @Francisco Thanks for the welcome. I agree with you. I should have made it clear (or left i out) that was something that could happen to a battery not charged for a long period of time.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your laptop probably has electrical damage as @Francisco said. Even if you replaced the battery, you would still have problems with your laptop as it has problems even when plugged in. You should have it looked at by a professional (or at least find out how much it would cost to repair compared to the price of a new laptop).